# angular2 consistent imports

Tags: typescript, angular

I am concerned that I can end up with conflicting imports within Angular2 and I would appreciate some guidance.

In component 1 I have the following:

```
// Services
//import {DataService} from './services/a2.DataService';
import {DataService} from '../../mocks/a2.mockDataService';
```

In component 2 I have the following:

```
// Services
import {DataService} from './services/a2.DataService';
//import {DataService} from '../../mocks/a2.mockDataService';
```

This seems plain wrong to me.  so I guess I am doin' it wrong!

I had expected to have a consistent set of imports specified in the app/main/bootstrap component and inherited by all components; A bit like stdafx.h being included everywhere.

Guidance please...

Comment: that's just not how ES6 modules work though. Each file is it's own module and needs to specify it's own imports. Also, what's wrong with your code, please don't make us guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing is correct.  Angular2 doesn't have an IoC Container like for example Laravel in php has, but Angular2 bootstrap is close!  But you can do some cool things doing it in this fashion.

So if we add a service to our bootstrap component, that service is the same service for the rest of our app.  What I mean by this is:

```
exports class myGlobalClass{
   var myGlobalVariable = 'Cheese';
}
```

When I call this class in any other module(As long as I bootstrapped it), I can get the value of `myGlobalVariable`, the reason this is really cool is for things like observables.  With observables it makes it easy for me to have a state change effect my entire application when I bootstrap a variable.

You still have to import this with a `import {myGlobalClass} from './globals'`, but it is the same Class/Object throughout the application.

But what if I don't want everything in my entire application to change on a state change?  What can I do to make it more 'local'?

```
exports class myLocalClass{
   var myLocalVariable = 'Local Cheese';
}
```

I would do an import into my component file of `import {myLocalClass} from './locals'`.  This makes a seperate class on each import so you can use this specific class on different views and not have to worry about one view changing another.

What can make this a little more challenging though is if I want myLocalClass to affect two different views.  Angular2 comes with additional tools to let you do this without too much headache, but you can see a little bit more clearly how Angular2 separates this out.

Also to add to toskv's comment, this is how importing does work in ES6.  I am not entirely sure if they are porting it down like they did with Node, where every module is compiled only once and distributed, or if each module is compiled seperately per call.  I would assume the latter but am not entirely sure, hopefully someone else can chime in.